# How to eliminate certain rows from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello so i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df= {'country_name':['Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Angola'],'commodity_code':['55','55','55','55'],'year':[2000,2000,2000,2000],'trade_value':[10000,12000,'NaN',105]}
```

Essentially, this is a long dataframe in which I have many countries from 2000 to 2020 and the trade value for commodity "55" and commodity "73". What I need is to eliminate those countries that never exported commodity 55 and commodity 73. I need to eliminate those countries that for every year for each commodity the column trade value equals 0, not NaN, thus they never exported the commodity.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example with countries that would be removed? And the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...: data = {
   ...:     'country_name': ['Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Angola'],
   ...:     'commodity_code': ['55', '55', '55', '55'],
   ...:     'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
   ...:     'trade_value': [10000, 12000, 'NaN', 0],
   ...:     }
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [2]: cond = df["commodity_code"].isin(["55", "73"]) & df["trade_value"].isin([0, "NaN"])

In [3]: df.drop(df[cond].index)
Out[3]:
  country_name commodity_code  year trade_value
0      Albania             55  2000       10000
1      Algeria             55  2000       12000

In [4]:
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do something like:

```
# ensure real NaN
df = df.replace('NaN', float('nan'))

mask = (((df['commodity_code'].isin(['55', '73'])
        &df['trade_value'].gt(0))
        |df['trade_value'].isna()
       ).groupby(df['country_name'])
        .transform('sum').gt(0)
        )

df[mask]
```

*NB. The condition on the year in unclear, but you could add 'year' if needed: `groupby(df['country_name', 'year'])`*

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the requirements right,
Here is what I understood, You need to drop the rows where the commodity is 55 and 73 and at the same time, their trade-off is either 0 or NaN.

Following code might work.

```py
import pandas as pd
df= {'country_name':['Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra', 'Angola'],
'commodity_code':['56','55','55','55'],
'year':[2000,2000,2000,2000],
'trade_value':[10000,12000,'NaN',105]}

df  = pd.DataFrame(df)

# if you to change your original data
df.drop(df[df.commodity_code.isin(['55', '73']) & df.trade_value.isin(['NaN', 0])].index, inplace = True) 

# In case you want the changes in separate dataframe
new = df.drop(df[df.commodity_code.isin(['55', '73']) & df.trade_value.isin(['NaN', 0])].index) 

# just convert it back into dictionary
df.to_dict("list") # OR new.to_dict("list")
```